# Landscape mode fix bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: this]

My app earlier was looking like this in the landscape mode, SO I wanted to use that right side space as well.

So I added the class `col-xs-4` to the `div` of the particular option.

So It looks like this now.

[image: this]

But the second collasper's click is becoming non clickable. How do I fix that??

Apologies for poor formatting.

Here's the code:

**show.html.erb file**

```
  <div class="container">
    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <h1><%= @garment.name %></h1>
     <div class="row">
      <%= form_tag proceed_orders_path, method: :post, id: "proceed_to_order_form" do %>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion"> 
        <%= render partial: "parts/part", collection: @garment.parts.reverse %>
        </div>
        </div>
       <% end %>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="proceed_to_order">Proceed</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**_radio_option.html.erb**

```
<% pre_disabled = radio_option.disablers.map(&:option).map(&:is_default?).first %>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 part_option_wrapper">
      <% if pre_disabled %>
      <div class='option_overlay'></div>
      <% end %>
      <label for="order_part_<%= radio_option.part.id %>_option_<%= radio_option.id  %>" class="option_radio_label">
    <%= radio_button_tag "order[part][#{radio_option.part.id}][option]", radio_option.id, radio_option.is_default?, class: "radio_option #{pre_disabled ? 'c_disabled' : ''}", "data-option-part" => radio_option.part.id, "data-option-name" => radio_option.name, "data-option-disables" => "#{radio_option.disables.map(&:disable_element_id)}", "data-option-subid" => "option_subid_#{radio_option.id}", "data-option-group" => "part_#{radio_option.part_id}", "data-option-enables" => "#{radio_option.enables.map(&:enable_element_id)}", disabled: (pre_disabled ? true : false) %>
    <%= image_tag radio_option.photo(:small), class: "radio_option_img", "data-option-part" => radio_option.part.id, "data-option-name" => radio_option.name %>
    <br><%= radio_option.name %>
       </label>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make simple working fiddle, i think you have some div closing tag extra

Comment: oops, not really, I have missed a div actually.

Comment: Yes the elements didnt have opening or close